# closing a resultset after return statement

Tags: java, mysql, connection, return

I have created a function in java to reuse every time I need to read a table from the database. My problem is that I do not know how to close the connection after the return statement. without doing that I am having problem with maximum connections reached in mysql.

here is my code:

```
public static ResultSet readTable(String query) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection conex = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cbr_flexible_db", "root", ""); 
        Statement st = conex.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);            
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return rs;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a very helpful helper method. The connection is hardcoded and doesn't come from a pool, and the `Statement` is left open! This is completely the wrong approach. I would recommend you abandon wheel reinvention, and use a connection pool and `try-with-resources` until you get to grips with libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you add a finally block, this should work:

```
 try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection conex = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cbr_flexible_db", "root", ""); 
    Statement st = conex.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(query);   
    return rs;         
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
finally{
    conex.close();
}
```

Comment: I tried using the finally statement but it runs before the return so I don´t recieve the result of the query...

Comment: No it runs after the return. The problem is that the connection and with it the rs is closed as well. As soon as the rs is closed you can no longer access it even if you already returned the rs. You should refactor your code and choose an approach where you close the connection when you no longer need to access the rs.

Comment: Why recommend a `finally` block when we've had `try-with-resources` for almost 5 years?!

Answer (score 0):

use finally block to clean resources like Statement, PreparedStatement, Connection and ResultSet etc. object.